# Ingesting Parquet file gives UTF-8 error [Druid 0.12.0]

Tags: parquet, aws-glue, druid

I've a AWS Glue generated Parquet file.  I've installed Parquet and Avro extensions (tried with 0.12.0 and 0.12.1 both) and I get following error in each case

$ >curl -X 'POST' -H 'Content-Type:application/json' -d @quickstart/master.parquet localhost:8090/druid/indexer/v1/task

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
<title>Error 500 </title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>HTTP ERROR: 500</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /druid/indexer/v1/task. Reason:
<pre>    javax.servlet.ServletException: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Invalid UTF-8 middle byte 0x27
 at [Source: HttpInputOverHTTP@149d71fc[c=8000,q=1,[0]=Content@519fed0b{HeapByteBufferR@67183cce[p=8000,l=8192,c=8192,r=192]={PAR1\x15\x04\x15\xC0\x81\x01\x15\xF4&apos;L\x15\xA0\t...X\xA2\xC7\x1c\xB7\xCc\x81\xC9\x1c\x984\x82I#s&lt;&lt;&lt;42\xC7\x1dt&lt;B\xC7\x1cs\xC0\xE3H\x1fx\xCc\x81...\xE2\x08$\xAa`R\x87#\xB0`RI\x1d\x90\xD4&gt;&gt;&gt;}},s=STREAM]; line: 1, column: 14]</pre></p>
<hr /><a href="http://eclipse.org/jetty">Powered by Jetty:// 9.3.19.v20170502</a><hr/>
</body>
</html>
```

== JSON config file ==

$ >more quickstart/master.json

```
{
  "type" : "index_hadoop",
  "spec" : {
    "ioConfig" : {
      "type" : "hadoop",
      "inputSpec" : {
        "type" : "static",
        "inputFormat": "io.druid.data.input.parquet.DruidParquetInputFormat",
        "paths" : "quickstart/master.parquet"
      }
    },
    "dataSchema" : {
      "dataSource" : "master",
      "granularitySpec" : {
        "type" : "uniform",
        "segmentGranularity" : "day",
        "queryGranularity" : "none",
        "intervals" : ["2010-03-01/2020-05-28"]
      },
      "parser" : {
        "type" : "parquet",
        "parseSpec" : {
          "format" : "timeAndDims",
          "dimensionsSpec" : {
            "dimensions" : [
            ]
          },
          "timestampSpec" : {
            "format" : "auto",
            "column" : "ndate"
          }
        }
      },
      "metricsSpec" : [
        {
          "name" : "count",
          "type" : "count"
        },
        {
          "name" : "collection_USD_SUM",
          "type" : "longSum",
          "fieldName" : "collection_USD"
        },
        {
          "name" : "order_count",
          "type" : "hyperUnique",
          "fieldName" : "orderNumber"
        },
        {
          "name" : "lead_count",
          "type" : "count",
          "fieldName" : "Sales.leads"
        }

      ]
    },
    "tuningConfig" : {
      "type" : "hadoop",
      "partitionsSpec" : {
        "type" : "hashed",
        "targetPartitionSize" : 5000000
      },
      "jobProperties" : {}
    }
  }
}
```

Any clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.you should modify this command (change master.parquet to master.json  ):  $ >curl -X 'POST' -H 'Content-Type:application/json' -d @quickstart/master.parquet
2. in the json config file ,the "paths" should be write the data path

Comment: I do not understand why it'd work? Curl expects json specs file instead of actual Parquet data file.

Comment: I'm getting this error now : "Can not construct instance of java.lang.Class, problem: io.druid.data.input.parquet.DruidParquetInputFormat" . Any help on that. Complete logs : https://s3.amazonaws.com/production.simplilearn.com/debug/log.txt

Answer (score 0):

check your s3 file data format and check the hadoop jar

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not construct instance of java.lang.Class, problem: io.druid.data.input.parquet.DruidParquetInputFormat

Comment: This is the s3 file I'm using : https://github.com/Teradata/kylo/tree/master/samples/sample-data/parquet

Comment: upload your master.json file ,i can not check this error